# Deciding the key names for search in object

Tags: javascript

Say, I have a continous stream of packets coming in with the format:

```
{
   id: "123",
   type: "a" // or b
}
```

Now I have create a object and decide its keys in a way that I check weather the incoming object exists in this or not.

One way I can achieve this by using the below format keys:

```
{
   "a_123": true,
   "b_456": true,
   "a_b_198": true
}
```

But this will go really ugly if I introduce a third type `c`. Can there be some elegant way to achieve this?

Also, I can not create multiple object, like one for `a` and `b` and so on.. since they would be coming over network and I want to minimise network latency.

Comment: Since all are `true` are you sure you need that `true` at all? I'd suggest rethinking the allowed formats Object. BTW your question is not exactly clear about what you're after with that *check* logic.

Comment: Can you rely on the fact that the object is `{id: "123", type: "a"}` or will it sometimes be `{type: "a", id: "123"}`? Also, your example "one way [you] can achieve this" leaves out the names of the properties. What if you get `{id: "123", type: "a"}` and `{foo: "123", type: "a"}`?

Comment: This true is just symbolic, since I want to do this in O(1) and hashmap seems like suiting for this. I am just concerned about what keys I should be keeping here... @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @void - Objects are not hashmaps. You'd probably be better off with a `Set` of strings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that seems like a good suggestion. But again for the set in what format should I store the string? "a_123", "a_864" <type_id>, doesn't seems like the best format to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a unique identifier for each object based on its properties. There are some things to consider. For instance, in JavaScript, `{id: "123", type: "a"}` and `{type: "a", id: "123"}` are slightly different objects, because their properties are in a different order. (Yes, properties have a defined order now. They always had some kind of order, but now they have a defined one.)

To be reliable, you'll need both the property names and their values, and you'll probably need them to be in a reliable order even if the object was constructed in slightly different ways (my `{id: "123", type: "a"}` vs. `{type: "a", id: "123"}` example).

I hate to say it, but given those constraints, it sounds like building a new object adding the properties in a defined order and converting it to string would be best. Since JSON will be built into your environment, it seems a reasonable way to stringify. For instance:

```
key = JSON.stringify(
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(originalObject)
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
    )
);
```

Then use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep the keys, using its `has` method to check for the key and its `add` method for adding it if not found.

Example:

```js
function makeKey(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(
        Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(obj)
            .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
        )
    );
}

const objects = [
    {id: "123", type: "a"},
    {type: "a", id: "123"},
    {foo: "123", type: "a"},
    {type: "a", foo: "123"}
];

const known = new Set();
for (const obj of objects) {
    const key = makeKey(obj);
    if (known.has(key)) {
        console.log(key, "already known");
    } else {
        known.add(key);
        console.log(key, "not known, added");
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I say "I hate to say it" because getting the object's keys, sorting them, building a new object, and then turning that into a string seems costly.

You could avoid creating the object and using JSON if the following are true:

- Your objects are flat
- You can pick a string that will be reliable as a delimiter between a property name and its value
- You can pick a string that will be reliable as the delimiter between properties

For instance, if you know property names will never contain `:` and property values will never contain `//--ooOOoo--//`, then:

```js
const NAME_DELIM = ":";
const PROP_DELIM = "//--ooOOoo--//";
function makeKey(obj) {
    let key = "";
    Object.entries(obj)
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .forEach(([name, value]) => {
        key += name + NAME_DELIM + String(value) + PROP_DELIM;
    });
    return key;
}

const objects = [
    {id: "123", type: "a"},
    {type: "a", id: "123"},
    {foo: "123", type: "a"},
    {type: "a", foo: "123"}
];

const known = new Set();
for (const obj of objects) {
    const key = makeKey(obj);
    if (known.has(key)) {
        console.log(key, "already known");
    } else {
        known.add(key);
        console.log(key, "not known, added");
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```